# Element not shown after use float left

Tags: css

In all `li` I use `float: left` for my buttons. but one of them not shown!
If I change this to float right everything is ok. but float left has problem.

[image: MyProblem Image]

My css code:

```
.btnEasyAccess {
    background-color: #1887e3;
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 12px;
        float: left;
        padding: 4px;
        margin-top: 4px;
        min-width: 75px;
        width: 75px !important;
}

.easy-access-list-container {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count:3;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.box-easy-access ul {
     list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.box-easy-access ul li span {
    display: inline-block;
}

.box-easy-access li {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px; /*vertical align*/
}

.box-easy-access li i {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.btn-submit {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 9px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: 'D5Sans', tahoma, Arial;
}
```

One thing is strange: if I change it with an inspect element. For example, `width: 75px`, this will appear.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle version?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line on your .btn-submit

```
-moz-user-select: none;
```

I belive your using firefox browser